# Timer Channel - Issue stdout inside loop

Tags: go, timer

I created an infinite loop to print "poet" but doesn't print anything in the console.

```
func main() {
    t := time.NewTimer(1 * time.Minute)
    for {
        k:=<-t.C
        fmt.Print("%T",k)
        fmt.Println("poet")
    }
}
```

Somehow, when I remove the below two lines , the program works fine

```
k:=<-t.C
fmt.Print("%T",k)
```

I am a newbie in Golang, please help me to understand what is causing this issue.Thank you

Comment: What do you expect to happen in each case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **Timer** type represents a **single event**, 
so when it happen here 
**`k:=<-t.C`**
you got deadlock - as all go-routines are asleep and you'll never get another time value inside the loop.

Below is example of using Timer, perhaps you wanted to use Ticker instead?

```
func main() {
    timer := time.NewTimer(time.Second * 2)
    <- timer.C
    println("Timer expired")
}
```

Comment: Hi can't we use <-timer.C inside loop?

Comment: No, it is not supposed to be used that way. It will simply block the loop.

Comment: Please see this example where both ticker and timer being used inside the loop https://mmcgrana.github.io/2012/09/go-by-example-timers-and-tickers.html#power-of-channels .

Comment: It is used inside switch and switch is inside a loop, such way you also able to run it inside a goroutine or many other ways, but that's not the point here. In the context of your question it is not a way it can be used, at least provide what are you trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

This will print 'poet' until the time expires.

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    now := time.Now()
    timeElapsed := true
    for timeElapsed {
        fmt.Println("poet")
        timeElapsed = (time.Since(now) < (1 * time.Second))
    }
    fmt.Println("Times up!")
}
```

Comment: @I did not get any warning, the console output was blank.Also how could we replace the loop with goroutine, both are used for different purposes aren't they?

Comment: @JishnuPrathap I have updated my answer to correctly match what you are after (after reading your comments). The `Timer` is not really what you want here, you can't effectively use that as a sentinel in the example provided.